# Benefit of index.js in component folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular

I see a tendency of having an `index` file in the component/container/module folders of react or angular2 projects e.g.

[angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/tree/master/src/app/about)

[react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/tree/master/app/containers/HomePage)

What is the benefit of this? When should it be used? Why simply naming the file same as the component it contains not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is for symplicity in the imports. In the style guide in Angular2 documentation, specifictly in the seccion [Create and Import Barrels](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#create-and-import-barrels), explain that is a technique for improve the number of files that are nessesary import when you use several elements of a component.